# LLDB - How to break on "something is written to stdout"?

Tags: c, lldb

I want to know if there is a way to set a breakpoint if something is written to stdout (or sterr).

Comment: `watch *stdout`?

Comment: In GDB, you can do `catch syscall write` to catch all usage of the `write` system call (so that catches a little more than you wanted).  Related: [How to 'catch syscall' in LLDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253347/how-to-catch-syscall-in-lldb)