# is it possible 'catch syscall' in LLDB now?

Tags: lldb

[Question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253347/how-to-catch-syscall-in-lldb), but that was almost 8 years ago.

I was wondering if it's now possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No:

```
(lldb) apropos syscall
No commands found pertaining to 'syscall'. Try 'help' to see a complete list of debugger commands.
```

This hasn't been requested enough to rise to the top of anybody's work queues.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, before this is finally implemented, a temporary workaround is trying to break at the `__sys_*()` libc functions, like `__sys_write()`. This would put you very close to the actual `syscall` instruction (at least in FreeBSD on amd64). Of course this won’t catch syscalls directly made by inline assembly…(i thought this is obvious) You may want to change all syscall instructions to int3 and check the first argument.

To catch those `write` syscalls using indirect syscall (`syscall()`, syscall number 0), break on `__sys_syscall()` then check the first argument for syscall number. Refer to `/usr/include/sys/syscall.h` in FreeBSD.

Comment: That won't catch syscall made directly in assembly.